# SQL Server to Snowflake - Load XML from CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, alteryx

I am trying to automate the data migration from **SQL Server** to **Snowflake** by leveraging **Alteryx** and **SnowSQL**.

Here are the steps:

1. create the database in SF
2. create the schemas in SF
3. create the tables in SF
4. download data from SQL Server to CSV files
5. stage the CSV files in SF
6. copy the files from staging to tables in SF

The process works fine except for **step #6** with one SQL Server data type: **XML**.

Let's get the table [*Production*].[*Illustration*] from the database [*AdventureWorks2017*] as an example.

In SQL Server, the table is created as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE [Production].[Illustration](
    [IllustrationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Diagram] [xml] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

The matching table in Snowflake is:

```
create or replace TABLE ILLUSTRATION (
    "IllustrationID" NUMBER(10,0),
    "Diagram" VARIANT,
    "ModifiedDate" TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)
);
```

Step 6 is performed with the following SnowSQL instruction:

```
COPY INTO AdventureWorks201789.Production.Illustration FROM @AdventureWorks201789.Production.%Illustration FILE_FORMAT= (FORMAT_NAME='my_csv_format') PURGE=TRUE;
```

This command raises this error:

```
    Error parsing JSON: <!-- Generated by Adobe Illustrator CS -> XAML Export Plug-In Version 0.17      --><!-- For questions
    File '@ILLUSTRATION/AdventureWorks201789.Production.Illustration.csv.gz', line 2, character 0
    Row 1, column "ILLUSTRATION"["Diagram":2]
```

Obviously, the problem is SnowSQL parses the data as if it was **JSON** whereas it should be **XML**.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to change this behavior in the documentation: [Snowflake Doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-csv)

The CSV file can downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ohiElWrKs8bQW34vuM6mEZpLTWiqVQwk).

Anyone up for the challenge?

Comment: Hi Lolo, if I'm reading this correctly I can see that there is a file_format in play which is a CSV type ('my_csv_format')...and this will need to be changed to an XML type: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#type-xml I would suggest creating this file_format and then trying to manually read from that XML file (why is it in a .csv and not .xml but that's another question) - and make sure that works before trying to run the process again. Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your comment!! 
The issue is the file is a real CSV containing one column in XML and it reflects what is possible with SQL Server: it is a mixed bag.
Unfortunately, changing the file format to XML doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried changing the data type for `Diagram` in SF from `VARCHAR` to `VARIANT`? That's the preferred data type for storing semi-structured data. Worth a shot, anyway.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the feedback! I actually tried the VARCHAR solution beforehand and it worked.
Can you explain the upside of using VARCHAR over VARIANT, please?
In this case, it wouldn't be possible to use the XMLGET or LATERAL FLATTEN functions.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your configuration, uploaded the file:

```
put file:///Users/gatil/Downloads/AdventureWorks2017.Production.Illustration.csv @mystage;
```

Created the table:

```
create or replace TABLE ILLUSTRATION (
"IllustrationID" NUMBER(10,0),
"Diagram" VARCHAR(16777216),
"ModifiedDate" TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)
);
```

Created a file format object (CSVFILE):

```
create FILE FORMAT MY_CSV_FILE 
COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' 
FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' 
RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' 
SKIP_HEADER = 1 
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042' 
TRIM_SPACE = FALSE 
ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE 
ESCAPE = 'NONE' 
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\134' 
DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
NULL_IF = ('\\N');
```

And run the copy command:

```
COPY INTO Illustration FROM @mystage FILE_FORMAT= (FORMAT_NAME= MY_CSV_FILE );
```

It loaded 5 rows successfully, and I can see that it did not try to convert them to JSON. Could you please check your file format object?

Comment: Hi Gokhan, I copied the wrong CREATE statement. My bad...
I was testing if it could be stored as a VARCHAR and it works as you noticed.
The [Diagram] column is actually a VARIANT in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, loaded it into snowflake with the VARCHAR(16777216) column as mentioned by Gokhan above, and then while processing the XML converted that column to XML using the PARSE_XML() function and it worked fine. Directly trying to process the VARCHAR data won't work, PARSE_XMl will convert the string to XML object which will allow XML related functions to interpret data.

Let me know incase of further questions and also let me know if it doesn't work.

All the best.

Cheers!